# Regex in Google sheet script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 regular expressions which work perfectly on regex101, but, on the sheet script, one (*REGEX_RANGO*) returns false when calling .test, and the other (*REGEX_INVIDIDUAL*) doesn't work at all.

(Note: I use a cell on the sheet to debug this kind of situation, I don't know if its a better one, if someone knows, please, post it!)

My current regular expressions are:

```
var REGEX_RANGO = /((?=(\d|\,))(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})+(?=(\s|\,)))/gm;
var REGEX_INDIVIDUAL = /((?<=,)|(?:^(\d)))[^(,|\-)\n]+((?=,)|(?:\s))/gm;
```

Why i need both? Well, I have a form, which people can join values and the regular expressions can work on them.

Inputs are like:

- `*000-005,100,200,250-275,300*`:

  - *REGEX_RANGO* should get on the array the values [000,005,250,275]
  - *REGEX_INDIVIDUAL* on another array should get [100,200,300]
- `*001,002,003,010-015*`:

  - *REGEX_RANGO*  should get on the array the values [010,015]
  - *REGEX_INDIVIDUAL* should get [001,002,003]

Hope someone knows how to handle this, thanks. You can find my current attemps 
[here](https://regex101.com/r/324JmA/1) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/mpn79z/2).

To be clear: this works ok on regex101, not on Google Sheet, maybe a scope or i need to scape the regular expression?

EDITED:

```
var REGEX_INDIVIDUAL = /((?<=,)|(?:^(\d)))[^(,|\-)]+(?=($|,))/gm;
var j = numeros_ingresados.match( REGEX_INDIVIDUAL )
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("F1").setValue( " >> j : " + j )
```

Comment: Can you add your desired output in the post please?

Comment: when I enter `000-005,100,200,250-275,300` with the `REGEX_RANGO` in regex101 I get the output you have with google app script

Comment: Sorry, i edited it

In regex101, it works, perfectly.

The thing is on google sheet script, it doesn't work at all, same input returns false (nor returns nothing) using string.test(REGEX_RANGO) or string.test(REGEX_INDIVIDUAL)

Thnx also to the admin who edited it, looks better!

Comment: can you write in your post the exact function you are using to make a match. Thx in advance

Comment: i'm using string.match(REGEX_RANGO) where string is the input from the user, and REGEX_RANGO of course the regex from the main post.

Comment: try to add the flags `g`an `m`as arguments but not as the main argument `string.match(regex[, indicators..] )`

Comment: Ok, i solved regex RANGO, i changed \s on the end to $. But REGEX individual still doesn't work at all on google sheet script.

@WiktorStribiżew, how i can choose the RE2? i cannot find it!

Comment: try : 

`var REGEX_RANGO = new RegExp(/((?=(\d|\,))(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})+(?=(\s|\,)))/, 'gm')
str.match(REGEX_RANGO);` same logic for INDIVIUAL

Comment: Wait, are you using that in the JavaScript code? Please add all the relevant code to the question. Note that GAS JS regexp does not support lookbehinds like `(?<=,)` in your second pattern.

Comment: @JSmith i changed REGEX RANGO (see the comment before you), it works now with the change but, with your method, REGEX INDIVIDUAL, still doesn't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, any way to replace it? not a pro on regex btw, i will try fixing that and see if it works. Refresh in some minutes, i will add part of the code i'm using on the main post.

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer that should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that GAS JS `RegExp` does not support lookbehinds like `(?<=,)` in your pattern.

You may use the following sample code to extract the values you need:

```
function extractRangos() {
  var s = "000-005,100,200,250-275,300";
  var REGEX_RANGO = /(?:^|,)(\d+)-(\d+)(?![^,])/g;
  var REGEX_INDIVIDUAL = /(?:^|,)(\d+)(?![^,])/g;
  var m, res_rango = [], res_ind = [];
  while (m = REGEX_RANGO.exec(s)) {
    res_rango.push(m[1]);
    res_rango.push(m[2]);
  }
  while (m = REGEX_INDIVIDUAL.exec(s)) {
    res_ind.push(m[1]);
  }
  Logger.log(res_rango);
  Logger.log(res_ind);
}
```

Result log:

[image]

**Regexp details**

The individual regex pattern is

```
(?:^|,)(\d+)(?![^,])
```

It matches

- `(?:^|,)` - start of a string or a comma
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `(?![^,])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is not a comma (the next char after the digits should be a comma or end of string).

The point is to collect only Group 1 values.

See [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zw3oFz/1)

The rango regex pattern is

```
(?:^|,)(\d+)-(\d+)(?![^,])
```

See [this online demo](https://regex101.com/r/2IyOME/1)

It matches:

- `(?:^|,)` - a non-capturing group matching the start of string or a comma
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(?![^,])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is not a comma.

The point is to collect only Group 1 and 2 values.

Comment: Both modes works perfect! Thanks

A note only: i replaced my REGEX_RANGO to /(?=(\d|,))(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})+(?=($|,))/gm and works like a charm with .match, but really really thanks for the code!

Comment: @lucas_7_94 `/(?=(\d|,))(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})+(?=($|,))/gm` is equal to `/(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})+(?=$|,)/gm` as the `(?=(\d|,))` requires the next char to be a digit or a comma, which is always true. Note the `+` after `)` should be removed.

Comment: Something new learned, need to improve, thanks so much for the info!

Comment: This! Note that GAS JS RegExp does not support lookbehinds! I couldn't figure out why I couldn't get mine to work. Do you know where I can find more info on what is supported and what isn't?

Comment: @StevenKuipers Sorry, GAS JS `RegExp` is really somewhat crippled, there seem to be issues with non-capturing groups, too (can't remember the issue though). [Here](http://www.javascript-spreadsheet-programming.com/2014/09/regular-expressions-part-2.html) is some interesting article, but I don't know if there is anything more comprehensive.